# Pull changes from branch develop to my feature

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow

I was working in a feature (feature/A) a few weeks ago, however, a new demand arose and I had to let the feature aside. So I created a new feature (feature/B) and worked in this demand till it was ready to merge it to the develop branch and so I did it.

How can I get those changes that are now in the develop branch to feature/A? I don't want to merge it yet, the feature is not finished.

ps: I imagine it's quite a simple thing to do, but none of the similar questions I read contemplated what I want to do. There was one telling me to create a temporary branch and merge the changes in it, but I think there's an easier way to do it, and I just don't know it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common way to achieve what you want: **merge** and **rebase**

Merge: The same you merged your feature/B to develop, you can merge develop to feature/A. *Note that by doing so, you don't respect git flow. So if sticking to this glow is important for you, you can go for a rebase.*

```
git checkout feature/A
git merge develop
```

Rebase: With this one, the root base of your branch will become the top of develop (a kind of way to correclty place your branch on top of a new base if you want).

```
git checkout feature/A
git rebase -i develop
```

By doing so, you'll have a complete control over your commits (drop, squash, or leave it as it).

If you are using a GUI tool for git, I'm pretty sure you'll manage to find those feature in it since they are quite common.